# Changing standard window maximize size

Tags: windows

You know the option to automatically hide the taskbar? If the taskbar is on the bottom of the screen the windows maximize height size is bigger or smaller whether you have the option on or not.

I was wondering if there is a way to change that max size value? If i could make all applications maximize height size 10 pixels shorter from the top? There's probably a registry value to change here!